# Setting application_name on Postgres/SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Looking at the output of `select * from pg_stat_activity;`, I see a column called `application_name`, described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW).

I see psql sets this value correctly (to `psql`...), but my application code (psycopg2/SQLAlchemy) leaves it blank.

I'd like to set this to something useful, like `web.1`, `web.2`, etc, so I could later on correlate what I see in `pg_stat_activity` with what I see in my application logs.

I couldn't find how to set this field using SQLAlchemy (and if push comes to shove - even with raw sql; I'm using PostgresSQL 9.1.7 on Heroku, if that matters).

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

the answer to this is a combination of:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect

> Any other connection parameter supported by the client library/server can be passed either in the connection string or as keywords. The PostgreSQL documentation contains the complete list of the [supported parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS). Also note that the same parameters can be passed to the client library using environment variables.

where the variable we need is:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME

> The application_name can be any string of less than NAMEDATALEN characters (64 characters in a standard build). It is typically set by an application upon connection to the server. The name will be displayed in the pg_stat_activity view and included in CSV log entries. It can also be included in regular log entries via the log_line_prefix parameter. Only printable ASCII characters may be used in the application_name value. Other characters will be replaced with question marks (?).

combined with :

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args

> String-based arguments can be passed directly from the URL string as query arguments: (example...)  create_engine() also takes an argument connect_args which is an additional dictionary that will be passed to connect(). This can be used when arguments of a type other than string are required, and SQLAlchemy’s database connector has no type conversion logic present for that parameter

from that we get:

```
e = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?application_name=myapp")
```

or:

```
e = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", 
              connect_args={"application_name":"myapp"})
```

Comment: Hmmm, wait. I'm not sure why, but this works fine on my development database (9.1.4/OSX) but not on Heroku's shared database (9.1.8/Linux) (getting `invalid connection option "application_name"`). Same SA version, same psycopg2 version, probably different libpq etc. But `psql application_name=foo_bar` works fine, both locally and against Heroku. Any tips on that?

Comment: that would be psycopg2 doing that.    try the psycopg2 connection directly and double check the version, as well as libpq version its built against.

Comment: For future readers, I'll note Heroku's libpq is from pg 8.4.9 by default. Looking at the [commit](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/8217cfbd991856d25d73b0f7afcf43d99f90b653) `application_name` was added, I believe it was after 8.4 was feature frozen. In a [chat](https://twitter.com/aknin/status/317730900093849600) with @craigkerstiens from Heroku, he confirmed that's the *probable* reason and suggested I vendor in a newer version of `libpq`.

Comment: Again, for future readers, here's the arduous way to [vendor new libpq into your Heroku slug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725974/setting-postgres-application-name-on-heroku) and set `application_name` successfully.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `asyncpg` driver, you should use

```
conn = await asyncpg.connect(server_settings={'application_name': 'foo'})
```

and if you're using `create_async_engine` of sqlalchemy, you can use,

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine

create_async_engine(
    ...
    connect_args={"server_settings": {"application_name": "app_name"}},
)
```

src - https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/204#issuecomment-333917251