# Error when Heroku app starts up

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm getting this error when my Heroku app starts up:

`invalid connection option "fallback_application_name"`

Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting PostgreSQL application\_name on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725974/setting-postgresql-application-name-on-heroku)

Comment: seems odd to me.  i'm not doing anything special and heroku is OOTB and works on my other apps.  i don't desire to set the application name to anything useful, i just dont want my app to crash

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a problem with heroku + postgres > 0.14

Here's the comment in my Gemfile that explains the details:

```
# Warning, if you remove the version number and end up with postgres > 0.14, expect this:
# #/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize': invalid connection option "fallback_application_name" (PG::Error)
# when trying to get app running on Heroku
gem 'pg', '=0.14.1'
```

Comment: I have had the same issue with pg 0.15.1, ruby 1.9.3 and 9.1, 9.2 and 9.3 versions os postgresql. Fixing the gem version to 0.14.1 and postgresql to 9.1 and now everything is working again.

Comment: To fix this, Install latest or compatible `postgresql93-devel` and `postgresql93-libs` yum packages (RPM) on the machine where gem is installed.