# How to send application_name to RPostgreSQL connection

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I know that PostgreSQL database allows to keep track of application name for each connection and it looks like application_name variable should work with RPostgreSQL, but how exactly should I do this? Adding variable application_name = "test" to dbConnect doesn't work.

Comment: application_name does not appear to be a parameter that you can set when connecting to a database: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

Comment: You mean in RPostgreSQL?

Comment: @hadley, 'application_name' appears in the page that you linked, it is definitely a parameter that you can set in PostgreSQL, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685861/setting-application-name-on-postgres-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @ncocacola ok must've missed that. You can set in `dbConnect()` in https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres

Comment: Great, thanks. @hadley just to check with you, are you planning to replace RPostgreSQL by RPostgres in dplyr?

Comment: @kismsu yes, eventually

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can pass `application_name='test'` as an argument to `dbConnect` in RPostgreSQL (there is an optional `options` argument, but I couldn't figure out what kind of data it expects).

An alternative would be to run the following SQL query immediately after opening the connection:

`SET application_name='test'`

and it should work until you close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's not well documented but something like this works:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, 
           dbname  = "<my_db>",
           host = "<my_host>", 
           [...], 
           options = "-c application_name=my_app_name"
       )
```

It works with `dbPool` too (package 'pool'):

```
pool <- dbPool(
            drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
            dbname = "<my_db>",
            host = "<my_host>",
            [...]
            minSize = 0,
            maxSize = 3,
            options = "-c application_name=my_app_name"
        )
```

Check with `pg_stat_activity`

```
mydb=> SELECT state, usename, application_name FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'mydb';
 state  | usename  | application_name
--------+----------+------------------
 active | postgres | psql
 idle   | myuser    | my_app_name
```