# How to set application_name for postgres connections?

Tags: java, postgresql, connection-pooling, tomcat-jdbc

I'm using tomcat connection pool `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`. The connections appear in my database `pg_stat_activity` with empty `application_name`.

How could I set that application name in my java app, so I know where each connection comes from (as there will be multiple applications accessing the same db)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could specify the application name in the connection string.
Documentation [here][1].

Example:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/DBNAME?ApplicationName=MyApp
```

**Take care**: the param names are case sensitive.
[1]: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/

Comment: @Gajus: I think that's only for libpq.  JDBC still uses `ApplicationName`, it seems

Answer (score 27):

Use set command:

```
set application_name to my_application;
```

Answer (score 8):

For those using normal connection string and not jdbc:

```
postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?application_name=myapp
```

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691283/

Answer (score 7):

You can add this to the JDBC URL that you use in your connection pool definition:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?ApplicationName=my_app
```

If you want to change it dynamically e.g. to reflect different modules *inside* your application, the you can use the [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) command as shown by klin.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python library `psycopg2`, here's how you can do

```
import psycopg2    
psycopg2.connect(host=host_ip, database=db_name, user=user, password=db_pwd, application_name="Python Local Test Script")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set programmatically, the PostgreSQL drivers also have a method you can call:

```
PGPoolingDataSource ds = new PGPoolingDataSource();
ds.setApplicationName(applicationName);
```